# Reading CSV file for Graph

Tags: reactjs, csv, d3.js

I know this is probably a stupid question, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass data from csv file to a component to display a graph in `d3`. I'm building the said graph in `reactjs` which I only started to learn a week ago.

After trying multiple solutions from online, this is the latest one I've tried:

```
class Visitors extends React.Component{

    constructor(){

        super();

        this.state = {

            data: []
        }            

        this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
    }

  componentWillMount() {


        var csvFilePath = "/lib/charts/data.csv";

        Papa.parse(csvFilePath, {
          header: true,
          download: true,
          skipEmptyLines: true,

          complete: this.updateData
        });
  }

  updateData(result) {
    const data = result.data;

    this.setState({data: data});

  }

    render(){

        let csvData = this.state.data.map(d => d);

        if(csvData.length > 0){

           let cd = 

                return(

                    <Fairway data={this.state.data}/>
                )

        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h3></h3>
                <div className="bottom-right-svg">
                    {cd }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};


ReactDOM.render(<Visitors/>,document.getElementById("top-line-chart"));
```

Data from CSV is reading fine, but I can't figure out how to pass that data to the component named `Fairway` where the graph will be built. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barely minutes passed since I posted this question and I figured out the solution. Here goes:

```
class Visitors extends React.Component{

    constructor(){

        super();

        this.state = {

            data: []
        }

        this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
    }

  componentWillMount() {

        var csvFilePath = "/lib/charts/data.csv";

        Papa.parse(csvFilePath, {
          header: true,
          download: true,
          skipEmptyLines: true,

          complete: this.updateData
        });
  }

  updateData(result) {
    const data = result.data;

    this.setState({data: data}); 

  }

    render(){

        if(!this.state.data.length)
            return null;

        return (
            <div>
                <h3></h3>
                <div className="bottom-right-svg">
                    <Fairway data={this.state.data}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};


ReactDOM.render(<Visitors/>,document.getElementById("top-line-chart"));
```